# How to get the name of a the student who got marks in all subjects bigger than and equal 80?

Tags: sql-server, oracle

I have the following table

```
Name  |  Subject  | Marks
 --------------------------
 a        M          70
 a        S          80  
 a        L          90
 a        G          100 
 b        M          80
 b        S          90  
 b        L          95
 b        G          100
 c        M          90
 c        G          100
```

Here I have a "Student" table I want to get the Name of the student who got marks in all subject bigger than and equal "80" from the student table like the following OUTPUT.

```
 Name 
 b
 c
```

Comment: what have u tried so far?

Comment: The `c` student didn't get all marks yet, why should it count as passing?

Answer (score 3):

A simple aggregation.

```
select   name
from     my_table
group by name
having   min(marks) >= 80
```

In the "real world" you'd be likely to have a separate student table with one row per student, and that might change the logic a little. The best implementation would likely depend on the average number of rows in the scores table per student.

Comment: It is really simple to understand your answer, thank you so much @David

Answer (score 3):

You have to use GROUP BY clause as follow. This is a classical question helping you to understand GROUP BY and HAVING clauses. GROUP BY realizes an aggregation while HAVING is allowing you to put a condition on it.

```
SELECT name
FROM student
GROUP BY name
HAVING MIN(mark) >= 80
```

Comment: what is difference vs @David Aldridge?

Comment: Thank you @Mihai anyway, I highly appreciated you

Answer (score 0):

Use a `CASE` expression to check for each row having more than or equal to 80.

**Query**

```
select t.Name from(
    select Name, Subject, Marks,
    case when Marks > 79 then 1 else 0 end as mark_status
    from your_table_name
) t
group by t.Name
having count(t.Marks) = sum(t.mark_status);
```

Answer (score 0):

Select name
from table 
where name not in ( Select distinct name where mark<80);

Comment: Have you tried to have a look at the execution plan?

Answer (score 0):

select distinct ss.name from Student ss

join (select name,count(*) q from student group by name)s on s.name=ss.name

join (select name,count(*) q from student where marks>=80 group by name)s1 on s1.name=ss.name

where s.q=s1.q

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
DECLARE  @Restult TABLE ([Name] VARCHAR(100), [Subject] VARCHAR(100), Marks INT)

INSERT INTO @Restult

 select 'a','M',  70
 union
 select 'a','S',  80
 union  
 select 'a','L',  90
 union
 select 'a','G',  100
 union 
 select 'b','M',  80
 union
 select 'b','S',  90
 union  
 select 'b','L',  95
 union
 select 'b','G',  100
 union
 select 'c','M',  90
 union
 select 'c','G',  100 


;WITH CTE AS
     (
         SELECT [NAME],
                SUM(IIF(r.Marks <80,1, NULL)) AS IsEightyExists             
         FROM   @Restult r
         GROUP BY r.[Name]
     )     



SELECT [Name]
FROM   CTE c
WHERE  IsEightyExists IS NULL
```