# Write a SQL statement to get the information of students with all subject score greater than 90

Tags: mysql

There is a MySQL table, named `scores`, to record the students' marks for all subjects. For example,

| name | class | score |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Oscar | Math | 100 |
| Oscar | Physics | 85 |
| Oscar | Biology | 90 |
| Tim | Math | 95 |
| Tim | Physics | 91 |
| Tim | Biology | 97 |
| Linda | Math | 85 |
| Linda | Physics | 87 |
| Linda | Biology | 85 |

Now, I want to find students whose scores of all subject are greater than 90. How can I write my SQL?

I use `group by` and `having` statement to divide scores by student name. But I don't know how to write my where clause. SQL is as below:

`select name from scores group by name having "every score" > 90`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the name of a the student who got marks in all subjects bigger than and equal 80?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47010138/how-to-get-the-name-of-a-the-student-who-got-marks-in-all-subjects-bigger-than-a) Also see [aggregate functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html) and [MIN()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_min).